# how to store vectors with different length into a matrix in R?

Tags: r

Say I have a list of vectors with different length such as:

```
listToMatrix <- list(c(1,2,3,4),c(2,15,6),c(9,1,4,6,2,5))
```

The question is how can I put this list into a matrix (it is OK to leave the blanks as zeros), because I want to vectorize the computation later.

Comment: You can vectorisations on lists, this isn’t a reason to store the data in matrix format (and, judging from this description, you should probably *not* store it matrix format).

Comment: what @KonradRudolph said, but `length<-` is a good function worth knowing about, `do.call(cbind, lapply(listToMatrix, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(listToMatrix))))`

Comment: By vectorization I mean doing simple matrix algebra calculations instead of using apply/sapply/mapply on my dataset.

Comment: I just realized that `sapply` would simplify it to a matrix for you, `sapply(listToMatrix, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(listToMatrix)))`

Answer (score 0):

We could use `stri_list2matrix` from `library(stringi)`.  We convert the output to `numeric` and change the dimension as the output matrix ('m1').

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- stri_list2matrix(listToMatrix, byrow=TRUE, fill=0)
`dim<-`(as.numeric(m1), dim(m1))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    0    0
# [2,]    2   15    6    0    0    0
# [3,]    9    1    4    6    2    5
```